# Turn on LED at a certain range

Tags: operational-amplifier

I wanted to design a circuit where the LED turns on when the voltage is in the range of 4.9 to 5V and same to that of charge with the range of 0.5 to 0.52. Can anyone help me with a basic circuit?

Comment: If you can live with >4.9V and <0.52V, look up window comparators.

Comment: By 'charge' could you possibly mean current?

Comment: YES sir , it would be current

Answer (score 0):

One [Example](https://www.mouser.in/pdfDocs/tps3701.pdf) for the voltage detection circuit:

Detailed design procedure is in section 8.2.2 of the datasheet:
[image]

The outputs are active low. I am doubtful about the accuracy though.There are some points in the doc, where by sacrificing little more power consumption, accuracy can be better.